# How do I save username and password using a "Remember me" checkbox in the login form?

Tags: 7

I want to save username and password using a *Remember me* checkbox. If I click it, the username and password should be save for future. In Drupal I am using Persistent login module to do this but I am not able to save the username and password.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You are merely listing your requirements, without asking any explicit question. (The title doesn't count as explicit question.) You should at least say what you tried and why it didn't work as expected. Did you look for any module on drupal.org? Keep in mind that module requests are off-topic for us, so questions asking to recommend or find a module are closed.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Remember me](https://www.drupal.org/project/remember_me) module doing the same job which you wants.

Comment: the username and password is not get saved if clicked on Remember me checkbox in Remember me module